# Locating thread leak in Node.js

Tags: node.js, multithreading

So I have this node application running on Ubuntu. And I noticed that there're lots of threads showing up form `pstree -a`

```
 └─node /bin/node --expose-gc -max-old-space-size=256 main.js
     └─process.title
         ├─sh ...
         ├─sudo ...
         │... bunch of scripts i'm doing
         ├─66*[{process.title}]
         └─5*[{node}]
```

Sometimes there're tens of them but it could go up to hundreds. And I have no idea how are they created, what are they doing. But for sure they are eating up system resources.

This project has complex package dependencies, so it becomes extream hard for me to locate the root cause of this problem. It will be very appreciated if someone could shed some light for me on this situation.

Comment: There are a base set of threads used by the node.js core (for things like file I/O).  Other than that, threads only come from modules with native code so you can start by examining the modules that contain native code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @jfriend00 's comment, it really helped me to narrow this down.

So [asyncawait](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) and its underlying [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) turn out to be the root cause in my case.

While I'm still not quite sure how this is happening (as this is a widely used module and doesn't seem to find anyone talking about this). But taking some time replacing all asyncawait with node native async brings the thread count back to 4.